# Is there an Anarchy equivalent in Borderlands 2?

Tags: borderlands-2

I always carried one Non-elemental gun in Borderlands 1: the [Anarchy SMG](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Anarchy) because of it's insane damage, firing 4 bullets per shot at a high rate of fire, all the while with decent damage per bullet to boot.

I haven't seen much like that in Borderlands 2 except early on I got a Blue SMG with red flavor text, [The gun of the Bulls](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Lascaux). It fired two bullets per shot, fired quickly and laid down a curtain of fire sort of like an Anarchy but less crazy.

What gun title/flavor text am I looking at for an Anarchy-like SMG? I know there's at least the gun I found, but I don't know how to recognize it. Are there other SMGs with more than one bullet per shot?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think they have been replaced with multibarrel miniguns and the like. I can't recall if I saw any non shotgun weapon that fired multiple shots.

Comment: the [bone shredder](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Bone_Shredder_(Borderlands_2)) also come close to being an anarchy from BL1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this in the Wiki under SMG's

```
Blagaga.: Very large clip and shoots 3 bullets at once.
```

[Special Weapon Effects Borderlands 2 Wiki](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Special_Weapon_Effects_Borderlands_2)

So there will be at least one that shoots 3 bullets at once. But I don't know how the gun is named nor where you can obtain it. Referring to [this](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/638784-borderlands-2/64141205) post, that I found, you can obtain it via the slot machines and it will be a orange item.

Comment: Ahah, that page is perfect! The gun I was talking about had "The gun of the Bulls" apparently http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Lascaux . Blagaga sounds closer to Anarchy though. Hopefully it's not slots-only

Comment: In my and my friends opinion, you have got enough money to spend it at the slots or even tip moxy your money. we are now level 25 and always have about 20-30k then spend all our money at the slots together and still have about 15k.

Comment: I probably should, really, since I lose like a half-hour's cash (which I don't use anyway) if I respawn now.